# Cyclotomic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory

How to prove that  $ (\zeta_{p^{n+1}}-1)^{p} $ = $ (\zeta_{p^{n}}-1) $ as ideals where $ \zeta_{n} $ is a primitive nth root of unity ?

Comment: False statements tend to be hard to prove.

Comment: It's not false. Look at Washington's book on cyclotomic fields in the appendix on infinite Galois theory and ramification.

Comment: Well they certainly have the same valuation.

Comment: I suspect that Emil made the mistake of looking at $\zeta_{p^0}-1$.

Comment: @Tom: My comment concerned the first version of the question, where it was impossible to guess that the OP is actually talking about ideals. It looked like a plain identity between two numbers (which were actually distinct).

Comment: Ah, now I see. Forgive my flippant comment. I am fond of the number zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\zeta _{p^{n+1}}=x$ say.Then, for every $\omega $ a $p$-th root of unity, $x\omega-1=x^r-1$ (for some $r$)  generates the same ideal as $x-1$ (clearly, it is contained in the ideal generated by $x-1$; by switching $x$ and $x\omega$ we get the other statement).

Taking the product over all the $\omega $ we now get the result you wanted.